# SSRS Permission settings in Report Service

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am running Report Service Manager - Web portal for accessing the Reports. For Development and Testing purpose, Report service is running from my computer.

Whenever Testing Team tries to access the web from their end, report service is asking an Initial Authentication of my computer account. ( Windows Authentication ). How to skip this authentication mode ? This is an Internal Application, i want Report service to run on any computer without asking any authentications.

Answer (score 1):

If you are all on the same domain, simply add "DomainName\All Users" with the appropriate role to the portal.  The testers *may* also need to add your site as a trusted site in their browsers.  "All Users" is exactly as it sounds - *any* user account on that domain will have the access you grant.

Alternatively, if you need to disable security entirely (**bad idea**), you'll have to configure a new security extension - it's *relatively* simple to do, especially with all the samples you can find online (google "SSRS custom authentication" or "SSRS anonymous authentication"), but if you've never done anything like this before, you may struggle if you run into any unexpected issues.

See here for one example on how to enable anonymous access:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jameswu/archive/2008/07/15/anonymous-access-in-sql-rs-2008.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I need SSRS anonymous authentication. As because, we are running the report service within our domain / network.